# Non Public API Usage and uniqueidentifier methods of UIDevice iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

I am done with development of my app. I made a shopping app which use Paypal API for payment. When I tried to upload the app it is giving following error. I am using Paypal API and UIDevice methods to get orientation. Please suggest any solution for this.

Thanks[image]

Comment: i facing same issue and yet not getting solution. in payPal intigration class oneof .a extation file contain uniqueidentifier  so apple found it as same as apple uniqueidentifier defined.

Comment: Use the latest payPal API or change the UDID  unique identifier access of device in the payPal API..

Comment: @Tony I am already using the latest paypal api. Also I have integrated its .a file. So I can not unique identifier access.

Comment: If PayPal API needs `unique identifier`, you can replace its code of fetching UDID using [***OpenUDID***](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID).

Comment: payPal 2.0.0? https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/blob/gh-pages/MPL/PayPalMPL_2-0-0-iPhone_DevelopersPackage.zip

Comment: ... and just to be sure: you don't have a method named `uniqueIdentifier` anywhere? That leads to false positives — Apple's uploader doesn't realise that you're calling it on something other than an instance of `UIDevice` (or, rather, can't really be sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get the source to the Paypal API?  Have a look at the fix Facebook just put into their API: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/56b40a4e75a5ab30cfbfb4197c69f092470b32f2#L13L1150

It appears that just assigning UIDevice to a variable triggers this?  This may change as Apple's heuristics get smarter...

Comment: @russal can you please more discribe this i facing the same issue in paypal while submit app then getting as error as like question and i use letest api of paypal but today i facing same issue please help me on this